# Get data inside an ng-repeat from an directive outside of it

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic-framework

I'm developing a mobile application using Ionic Framework based an AngularJS.

On one directive I'm looping over a JSON Array with `ng-repeat` applying a condition with `ng-if`, see below:

```
<ion-content class="has-header has-subheader" >

<ion-slide-box">
<ion-slide
    ng-if="invocation.title_id == titleid" 
    ng-repeat="invocation in invocations" >

    <h3>{{invocation.id}}</h3>
    <div ><h1>{{invocation.invocation_frensh }}</h1></div>
    <div ><h1>{{invocation.invocation_ar}}</h1></div>
    <div ><h1>{{invocation.invocation_franko}}</h1></div>
    <div ><h1>{{invocation.comments_fr}}</h1></div>
    <div ><h1>{{invocation.comments_ar}}</h1></div>
  </content>
</ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>

<p>{{invocation.id}}</p>

</ion-content>
```

The point is that on the last `p` nothing is shown.

I understand that the $scope is not the same but on the last `"p"` or any other component outside the `ng-repeat` I need to have the same data in order to interact with it.

For exemple I want to add a button on a footer that gets the `"{{invocation.id}}"`. If invocation.id equals 3 inside the `ng-repeat "h3"` I want to have it equals 3 in the `"p"`

How can i do it ?

Thanks for you help

**Edit:** In fact I want invocations[index].id in the 'p' outside of the loop, where index equals the displayed slide.

Comment: Invocation doesn't make sense outside of the loop. Which invocation object do you want to reference in the p tag?

Comment: What if it's repeated multiple times - which invocation.id do you want to show in the footer? The last one?

Comment: Thanks for comments. I want to see the same invocation.id that the one being displayed on the loop. Should I say on the ion-slide to be more specific.

Comment: In fact I want invocations[index].id in the 'p' outside of the loop, where index equals the displayed slide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `invocation` variable dies when the `ng-repeat` ends, if you need to use it again, you will need another `ng-repeat`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to show only one slide at a time, you could do it without `ng-if`, and use filter instead.

```
<ion-slide ng-repeat="invocation in displayedInvocations = (invocations | filter:{title_id: title_id}:true)">
```

and then at outside:

```
<p>{{displayedInvocations[0].id}}</p>
```

Hope this helps.